How do I unlock/get Gestures for P-BODY and ATLAS in Portal 2?
Under the "Robot Enrichment" section of Portal 2, there seems to be an option to customize gestures for P-BODY and ATLAS, but I don't have anything unlocked or anything in there:


How do I unlock/get Gestures for P-BODY and ATLAS in Portal 2?

Some gestures can be unlocked by playing through the co-op part of the game, while others used to be purchasable:
Gestures for Atlas | Gestures for P-body
You can still get the purchasable gestures to work using commands, though. See this Steam guide for easy instructions (including binds in the comments!). I doubt they will show up in the menu, however.

(And if you're looking for someone to play the co-op part with, let me know :)
